# Any ways to display Google web / custom search results, into another UI?

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, google-search

I have currently a program written in html / javascript related to the Google search API which functions when users search a place, information and local places on it will be returned.

Google custom search and web results have a standard "UI" for their results returned. I would like to display them in my personal UI, etc maybe in a drop down list or textfield.

I know for Google local search your able to retrieve them and use in other places through values like res.address and res.title.

However, i could not find any information regarding the web search or custom search control.
Is retrieving and displaying it in another UI possible? Would appreciate any help, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

According to the Google Custom Search documentation found here:
http://www.google.com/cse/docs/resultsxml.html#xmlNotes

You can pull the results back via an XML field which would give you the desired control I believe you are looking for.

Answer (score -1):

or you can make an ajax call to google's search api

http://code.google.com/apis/ajaxsearch/